# How do I display multiple rows of data from mysql in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How do I display multiple rows of data in `ListView`?

Now I am only able to retrieve and display one data(Item) at a time, I want to retrieve multiple rows of data(Items) and display all them in `ListView`.

In this case, I am using the name of the user to retrieve the coupons he/she have in the database. So for i can only display one coupon and I want to know how to display multiple coupon in `ListView`.

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));


            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_all_coupons, "GET", params);


            Log.d("Single Voucher Details", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_COUPONS); // JSON Array


                JSONObject coupons = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate the `ListView` I suggest you create a `List` of objects (vouchers) and create an `Adapter` that knows how to display any number of coupons in the list. First of all you may want to define a simple class for your coupons (reimplement it according to your data structure):

```
public class Coupon {
    private String mCouponText;

    public Coupon(String text) {
        mCouponText = text;
    }

    public String getCouponText() {
        return mCouponText;
    }
}
```

After that you should create a List of these objects from your `JSONArray`. There are different approaches, one of them:

```
List<Coupon> couponsList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray coupons = json
            .getJSONArray(TAG_COUPONS); // JSON Array
for (JSONObject coupon : (Iterable<JSONObject>) coupons) {
    String text = coupon.get("text");
    couponsList.add(new Coupon(text));
}
```

And the last thing to do is to create an `Adapter` and set it as an adapter of your `ListView` in your `Activity`:

```
ArrayAdapter<Coupon> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, couponsList);
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After that the `ListView` will use the `Adapter` to populate its rows. You may want to implement your own adapter since it gets you far more options, you'll easily find out how to do it.

**Update**

Consider using [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class call it anything you like (lets call it Item), and each instance of this call will represent relevant row in the `Database` ( or any source from where you are getting the information)

```
Item.java may have few instance variable like coupons and userName,

public class Item {

    private String coupons;

    private String userName;

    public String getCoupons() {
        return coupons;
    }

    public void setCoupons(String coupons) {
        this.coupons = coupons;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Make a `Arraylist` of type `Item` and feed this information to a custom `ListView` to show the details you want it to.

```
ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setCoupons(""+productObj.getJSONObject(i).getString("CouponKey"));
            list.add(item);
        }
```